# Windows XP doesn't load libstdc++6.dll from MinGW/bin but loads from exe dir

Tags: c++, mingw

I recieved the following error after compiling jsoncpp-src-0.5.0 with scons. The executables generated, are presumably not able to load libstdc++6.dll from the MinGW/bin dir though it is on the PATH.

```
the procedure entry point _gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++6.dll
```

Placing the dll into the executable's folder relieves this error. What could be causing this?

Comment: You probably have more than one file called `libstdc++6.dll` and the DLL load rules are selecting the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for (a lot of) details on how Windows searches DLLs for your application. It appears that the application's executable directory is always searched first.